Cannot get imap.append to send date
I am writing a very basic email client as part of a larger project, and have one problem. Using SMTP, the email is sent, all is well. I am using IMAP to send a copy of the email to the "Sent Items" folder. That works as well, except for one thing. imap.append is not setting the date. The email gets copied, but without a date.
The code is very basic. Create the date:
date_now = imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time())

I log in, etc. Then the imap.append call:
imap.append('"Sent Items"', '\\Seen', date_now, text.encode('utf8'))

No date on the sent email. I have checked the results of the date_now output, which is what it should be:
"03-May-2024 11:32:54 -0600"
Any suggestions?
Some have requested more code to see everything that is going on, so here it is. (The form values are being correctly sent, as I said the SMTP email goes through OK):
receiver_email = request.form['Email']
    sender_email = 'user@server.local'
    sender_password = 'xxxxxxxx'
    msg_subject = request.form['EmailSubject']
    msg_text = request.form['EmailText']
    msg_attachment = request.form['EmailAttachment']
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message_text = msg_text
    message['Subject'] = msg_subject
    message['From'] = sender_email
    message['To'] = receiver_email
    message.attach(MIMEText(message_text))
    text = message.as_string()
    
    smtp_server=smtplib.SMTP("x.x.x.x",587)
    smtp_server.ehlo() 
    smtp_server.starttls()
    smtp_server.ehlo()
    smtp_server.login(sender_email, sender_password)        
    smtp_server.sendmail(sender_email,receiver_email,text)

    date_now = imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time())
            
    imap = imaplib.IMAP4("x.x.x.x", 143)
    imap.login(sender_email,sender_password)
    imap.append('"Sent Items"', '\\Seen', date_now, ext.encode('utf8'))
    imap.logout()


Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. If you're not sure what to include, check out [ask].

What is the IMAP server response to that command? What exactly is contained in the variable text?

This is not surprising.  The Date header gets added by the mail server if the message does not contain one, but you are bypassing the mail server.  You should be able to add the Date: header you want before you do the sending.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Each message has two dates (and then some more). If you send a message at 10:01:00 and it arrives in the recipient's inbox at 10:02:00, the former date is available in the Date: field and in the IMAP ENVELOPE structure. The date you're setting using APPEND is the latter.
If you want to set the former, you need to construct a Date: header field. (And you probably do want that, since it's required.)
